# Java Array index counter recursive

Tags: java

How to reassign java array index counters? Let say i have 3 length array. If we are getting 4th element from the array, compiler will give Index out of Bounds exception. Can we avoid this exception so that the 4th element should give 1st element. index 3 should give 0th element, index 4 should give 1st element. etc

Comment: There is nothing built in into the Java language to do this.

Comment: modulo (%) your array size is what you need, but i dont think that it wise to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use a modulo operation:

```
int safeIndex = index % array.length;
```

If that's too low-level, then there are different libraries that offer Stream-based solutions:

Here's a version using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s `FluentIterable`:

```
FluentIterable.from(Iterables.cycle(Arrays.asList(array))).get(index)
```

And here's one using [JavaSlang](http://www.javaslang.io/) streams:

```
Stream.of(array).cycle().drop(index).get();
```

Java 8 streams do not offer this functionality, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the *modulo* operator `%`:

```
Object element = array[index % array.length];
```

Comment: As an addition, it would be wise to apply the modulo operator when increasing the index rather than just when addressing the array elements, if this index is only used to address elements of the array and the array doesn't change size (it would avoid overflowing the index datatype in the long run)